# Являются ли вопросы "Как сделать X" и "Как сделать X средствами чистого с++" дубликатами

Tags: обсуждение, дубликаты

где X в общем случае требует нетривиальных сторонних библиотек, хотя относительно несложно реализовать руками тривиальные случаи.

Ответы на просто "Как сделать X" почти наверняка будут сторонние библиотеки использовать.

Автор вопроса с *"чистым С++"* поясняет, что нашёл библиотеки A, B, которые справляются с задачей, но пишет *"мне бы хотелось самому все это написать"* [не используя библиотеки]

Являются ли вопросы "Как сделать X" и "Как сделать X средствами чистого с++" дубликатами?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

На мой взгляд нет. Они, безусловно, являются связанными, но дубликатами их объявлять не стоит. Очевидно, что нельзя объявить вопрос с библиотеками дубликатом вопроса без библиотек. Что же насчёт обратного объявления?

1. Если кто-то будет искать именно без библиотек и напишет это в поисковом запросе, удобно, чтобы нашлась соответствующая версия, из которой не надо отсеивать половину ответов как неподходящие.
2. Что если вопрос без библиотек был задан первым? Мы не можем закрыть новый вопрос как дубликат поскольку он более общий, а если закроем старый, то ответы-то останутся в нём, а в новом соответствующих ответов без библиотек может и не появиться. Получается, мы посылаем нашедших вопрос по ложному пути.

Дубликатами следует объявлять только

1. те вопросы, которые могут быть задубликачены в любом направлении
2. вопросы о базовых проблемах, для которых есть эталонный более широкий ответ
   и то я в таком случае не против [опубликовать конкретный ответ](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4971/178988) перед закрытием

Comment: А как быть с гражданами которые не хотят использовать стандартуную библиотеку С++ а только С либы? Так уже выходит 3 варианта ответов.

Comment: @AndrioSkur, си++ и си - это два разных языка, где-то есть тема, в которой это обсуждалось. Вопросы о разных языках не могут быть дубликатами.

Comment: Прикол в том что человек пишет на с++, но не хочет использовать (std::vector, std::sort, std::string). Только (malloc, qsort, char*), вот и получаеться что хотя метка с++ на самом деле используеться с.

Comment: @AndrioSkur, ну так и что?

Comment: Ну это нормально что у нас будет 3 вопроса, которые отличаються только непонятным желанием авторов об использовании сторонних библиотек? Если норм, то вопросов нет.

Comment: @AndrioSkur, почему сотня вопросов "как написать цикл по массиву и в нём <разное действие>" - это нормально, а 3 вопроса с разными ограничениями на библиотеки - нет? Да, нормально.